# object.push(array) is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, for-loop

I am using for loop to get the units onebyone and inside loop I am getting the array of volumes like below. now I want to push that array to respective unit so I used push but here I am getting error.

**My code is below**

```
$scope.UnitDetails = [{
                       UnitId : "001"
                       Unit1 : "A"
                       Fields: [{"one" : "true","Isactive" : true },
                                 {"two" : "false","Isactive" : true }
                               ]
                      },
                       {
                       UnitId : "002"
                       Unit1 : "B"
                       Fields: [{"one" : "true","Isactive" : true },
                                 {"two" : "false","Isactive" : true }
                               ]
                      }]
     for(i= 0; i < $scope.UnitDetails.length ; i++){     
                var volume = [];                
                volume.Volume_AL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.AL);
                volume.Volume_BL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.BL);
                volume.Volume_CL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.CL);
                volume.Volume_DL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.DL);
                $scope.UnitDetails[i].push(volume);
            }
```

Can anyone find where i am doing mistake

**EDIT**

When I try as below then it is creating another array in object as below

```
 for(i= 0; i < $scope.UnitDetails.length ; i++){     
                    var volume = {};                
                    volume.Volume_AL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.AL);
                    volume.Volume_BL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.BL);
                    volume.Volume_CL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.CL);
                    volume.Volume_DL = eval($scope.VolumeFormula.DL);
                    $scope.UnitDetails.push(volume);
                }
```

**What I got**

```
   $scope.UnitDetails = [{
                           UnitId : "001"
                           Unit1 : "A"
                           Fields: [{"one" : "true","Isactive" : true },
                                     {"two" : "false","Isactive" : true }
                                   ]
                          },
                           {
                           UnitId : "002"
                           Unit1 : "B"
                           Fields: [{"one" : "true","Isactive" : true },
                                     {"two" : "false","Isactive" : true }
                                   ]
                          },
                           { 
                             Volume_CL:0,
                             Volume_EQ:12,
                             Volume_PH:54,
                             Volume_RW: 24
                        }]
```

My Expected :

```
  $scope.UnitDetails = [{
                           UnitId : "001"
                           Unit1 : "A"
                           Fields: [{"one" : "true","Isactive" : true },
                                     {"two" : "false","Isactive" : true }
                                   ]
                           volume : [ { 
                             Volume_CL:0,
                             Volume_EQ:12,
                             Volume_PH:54,
                             Volume_RW: 24
                                      }]
                          },
                          {
                           UnitId : "002"
                           Unit1 : "B"
                           Fields: [{"one" : "true","Isactive" : true },
                                     {"two" : "false","Isactive" : true }
                                   ]
                          volume : [ { 
                            Volume_CL:0,
                             Volume_EQ:12,
                             Volume_PH:54,
                             Volume_RW: 24
                                     }]
                          },
                        ]
```

Comment: Do you by any chance mean `$scope.UnitDetails[i] = volume`…?

Comment: what is `$scope.UnitDetails` ?

Comment: Did you by any chance mean `var volume = {};`? Also showing the error you are getting might be useful. It seems pretty strange to me to ask on a public forum why I am getting an error and not actually showing the error that I am getting.

Comment: What Error are you getting.

Comment: I am Storing my object in $scope.UnitDetails

Comment: Cool, but what is this `$scope.UnitDetails` variable? Where is it declared? How is it declared? I hope you realize that from the perspective of someone without a magic crystal ball able to read other people's minds/codes it is pretty hard to be able to help.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar `TypeError: $scope.UnitDetails[i].push is not a  function`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I understand but it is a normal object. It was declare Outside and  I am getting values inside loop also `EX: $scope.UnitDetails[0]`

Comment: Sure, can you show your code? More specifically where and how you declared the `$scope.UnitDetails` variable? The `push` function operates on arrays. Is `$scope.UnitDetails[i]` an array? Hard to say without seeing your code. Obviously judging from the error you are getting it is not an array, but how can you possibly expect someone to help you without knowing what code you might have written?

Comment: To put value in array we do like this array[index] = "value" and for object  its obj.property = "value". Here you are adding value to your array like an object.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It is an object not an array, I already mention in comment it as  object. I want to add this volume to it

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar Please check the updated question for object sample structure. Now I am trying to place volume as fields in that object

Comment: OK, now that you have shown your code it is clear where the problem is. There are 2 problems actually. First is that you need to declare the `volume` variable as an object as shown in my first comment and second is that you need to call the push method on the array: `$scope.UnitDetails.push(volume);` instead of `$scope.UnitDetails[i].push(volume);`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov when I tried as you suggested I am getting another array inserted in object as in Edited question. But Iike to add this volume fields array in every array in object.

Comment: It's unclear what the expected result is. Please show the expected result object. When you ask a question on StackOverflow please don't forget to show what the expected and actual results are (in addition to the code you have tried to achieve the expected result).

Comment: Excellent, now your question can be answered. Will have to wait for the community to approve it being reopened (I already voted for that). Once this happens I can provide an answer on how to achieve the desired result. Next time you ask a question on StackOverflow make sure you provide the necessary details to avoid getting closed like this one.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov apologies for asking question which is unclear.Thanks for quick replies and your time. Expecting for your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143689/discussion-between-charan-tej-and-darin-dimitrov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired result you could append the `volume` array dynamically to each element of `$scope.UnitDetails`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.UnitDetails.length; i++) {
    $scope.UnitDetails[i].volume = [{
        Volume_AL: eval($scope.VolumeFormula.AL),
        Volume_BL: eval($scope.VolumeFormula.BL),
        Volume_CL: eval($scope.VolumeFormula.CL),
        Volume_DL: eval($scope.VolumeFormula.DL)
    }];
}
```

Remark: The `eval` statement allows for execution of arbitrary javascript code and if the input is coming from your users you might want to ensure that it doesn't contain any malicious code before passing it to this function. Or even better do not use `eval` at all. Depending on your requirements you might find a more appropriate and restrictive function to achieve your goal. For example if you are expecting to evaluate only mathematical expressions written from your clients you might find a library designed exactly for this purpose rather than using the general purpose `eval` statement.

Comment: How to give single line if condition to check null in that eval. like if that `eval statement` returns NAN or undefined then store as 0